# minitest/capybara error - NameError: undefined local variable or method 'page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, minitest, testunit, ruby-2.7

I'm in the process of updating the hosting for a Rails 3.2 LTS project, taking them from ruby 2.3.3 to 2.7.2.

As part of this I've updated a few gems, specifically updating

- minitest from 5.11.3 to 5.14.3
- capybara from 1.1.2 to 2.18.0
- shoulda-matchers from 1.0.0 to 2.1.0
- shoulda-context from 1.0.0 to 1.2.2

I mention all this, because I've now got two failing tests, which were passing before the changes.

```
Error: test_: as a logged in user who has picked a location with an existing current visit when requesting the edit visit page should show the clinical coronal balance section. (VisitsControllerTest): NameError: undefined local variable or method `page' for #<VisitsControllerTest:0x0000558981845048>
test/functional/visits_controller_test.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <class:VisitsControllerTest>'
test/functional/visits_controller_test.rb:109:in `instance_exec'
test/functional/visits_controller_test.rb:109:in `block in create_test_from_should_hash'

Error: test_: as a logged in user who has picked a location with an existing current visit when requesting the edit visit page should show the clinical sagittal balance section. (VisitsControllerTest): NameError: undefined local variable or method `page' for #<VisitsControllerTest:0x0000558981844dc8>
test/functional/visits_controller_test.rb:122:in `block (4 levels) in <class:VisitsControllerTest>'
test/functional/visits_controller_test.rb:134:in `instance_exec'
test/functional/visits_controller_test.rb:134:in `block in create_test_from_should_hash'
```

These are both pointing to two tests within the same file, which look like this

```rb
should "show the clinical coronal balance section" do
  assert page.has_table? 'clinicalassessment'
  assert page.has_selector? 'td', :text => "Coronal Balance\n(mm)", :count => 1
  assert page.has_selector? 'td', :text => 'S1-T1 (Global)', :count => 2
  assert page.has_field? 'clinical_assessment_permutation_with_brace_pre_adjustment_coronal_balance_global_negative', :count => 1
  # snip
end

should "show the clinical sagittal balance section" do
  assert page.has_table? 'clinicalassessment'
  assert page.has_selector? 'td', :text => "Sagittal Offset\n(mm)", :count => 1
  assert page.has_selector? 'td', :text => "Wall to Foot Template", :count => 1
  assert page.has_selector? 'td', :text => "Wall to S1", :count => 1
  assert page.has_selector? 'td', :text => "Wall to T1", :count => 2 # this matches T1        
  # snip
end
```

As mentioned, this test was passing before, so I'd guess something has changed in one of the gems, but I don't know what, or how to fix it.

My `test_helper.rb` file is below

```rb
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require 'minitest/autorun'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/minitest'

User.work_factor = 4

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  # raise "remove workaround" if Shoulda::VERSION > "2.11.3"
  unless defined?(Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError)
    class Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError < ActiveSupport::TestCase::Assertion
    end
  end

  def assert_false(expected_to_be_false, message = "")
    assert !expected_to_be_false, message
  end

  alias deny assert_false
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  # Make `assert_*` methods behave like Minitest assertions
  include Capybara::Minitest::Assertions

  # Reset sessions and driver between tests
  # Use super wherever this method is redefined in your individual test classes
  def teardown
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end

class Minitest::Test
  def page
    Capybara::Node::Simple.new(@response.body)
  end
end

require 'mocha/setup'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're including Capybara::DSL into ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest which should make `page` available in any tests derived from that class.  Since you're getting that `page` is undefined it would imply that whatever class those tests are derived from (it's not shown in your question) is not ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

On a side note - I would be surprised if Capybara 2.18 doesn't have some issues with Ruby 2.7 (at the very least a ton of warnings)

Comment: The test in question was extending `ActionController::TestCase`, so I changed it to `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`, and now it's failing with the error `undefined method respond_with`. And yes, there are a lot of deprecation warnnigs with 2.7, but we're suppressing them for now (until we're able to update Rails)